# permissions issue committing to SVN repository on new server

Tags: svn, permissions

i recently moved my svn repositories to a new server with the same path structure without a hitch. i changed the DNS so that the domain name points to the new server (and the interweb DNS pipes are aware of this). therefore, i didn't have to update working copy's repo URL (in svn info). i can check out a new copy just fine, but committing a change gives me errors:

```
me$ svn ci -m "testing svn ci on new server"
Sending        trunk/www/index.php
Transmitting file data .svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Can't open file '/var/svn/webrepo/db/txn-current-lock': Permission denied
```

ok, so i try to sudo the same check-in command, with this error:

```
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: To better debug SSH connection problems, remove the -q option from 'ssh' in the [tunnels] section of your Subversion configuration file.
svn: Network connection closed unexpectedly
```

i've seen this similar problem in forums with a solution of either updating the working copy URL or fixing the remote permissions. the URL should be ok in my case, and I'm stuck trying to fix the permissions. i can ssh just fine with my local users. This is the remote repository permissions:

```
drwxrwxr-x 6 svn svn 4096 Feb 20 07:33 webrepo
```

the svn group contains my remote user account with which i ssh in. i have tried chown'ing -R to that user directly, as well as root and have had no luck. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same problem after moving svn to a new server running on linux. SVN runs as www-data user & the repo & all files & sub directories has to be owned by www-data. Mostly this is the case but some files where owned by root. By running

```
chown www-data 'new-repo' -R
```

it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

All the files in the same repo has this rights: drwxrwxr-x? And the user used for testing purpose is in the appropriate group? I mean with this rights above, only the owner user, and the owner group have the right to write files, and it can cause trouble, if you try to commit something.

Have you tried to compare

- the "users" file
- the repo directory (recursively)

on the two machines?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to mention in clear text

- which protocol you use to access repo (from context discovered svn+ssh://, yes)
- under which user you ssh to repo-host
- Is it shared or single-user repo

Read [Tunneling over SSH](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.sshauth) topic in the SVN book in order to understand permissions issues in deep, mostly around this text

> In this example, the Subversion client is invoking a local ssh
>   process, connecting to host.example.com, authenticating as the user
>   harryssh (according to SSH user configuration), then spawning a
>   private svnserve process on the remote machine running as the user
>   harryssh.

and "SSH Configuration Tricks"

In short - you have wrong owner, and maybe, bad permissions

Comment: i'm not sure what i did to fix the issue, but now it works. i did chown of the svn repos recursively to 777 then back to 755. but that doesn't seem like that would have fixed it.

-yes i am using svn+ssh://
-i ssh into the host with a user in the svn group.
-it's a single-user repo

anyway, thanks for your replies!